# EXPIRE Redis key if not modified

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Is there a straightforward way to EXPIRE a redis key if the value has not been modified in the last x minutes?

I doubt this is possible - but I am wondering if there is native solution or something with very little logic and/or extra state.

Now, this behavior might already be present - I invoke EXPIRE on a key. Then if I call SET on that key I can call EXPIRE again and the key will EXPIRE with the new value not the old?

Comment: I have the same scenario, so i did as you said. Whenever, I access the key i extend its expiry with a new value.. That it is.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct, just do expires one over another.

EXPIRE does not accumulate or reset or anything, it just sets the timer to the new value.

Example (w/o error handling for verbosity):

```
'use strict';

let client = require('redis').createClient()
const KEY = 'my:key';
const TTL = 10;
let value = 'some-value';

client.on('ready', function() {

  console.log('Setting key...')
  client.set(KEY, value, function() {

    console.log('Setting expire on the key...');
    client.expire(KEY, TTL, function() {

      console.log('Waiting 6 sec before checking expire time...');
      // Check in 6 seconds, ttl should be around 6
      setTimeout(function() {

        client.ttl(KEY, function(err, expiryTime) {

          console.log('expiryTime:', expiryTime); // "expiryTime: 6" on my system
          // expire again to show it does not stack, it only resets the expire value

          console.log('Expiring key again...');
          client.expire(KEY, TTL, function() {

            // again wait for 3 sec
            console.log('Waiting 3 more sec before checking expire time...');
            setTimeout(function() {

              client.ttl(KEY, function(err, expiryTime) {

                console.log('New expiryTime:', expiryTime); // 7
                process.exit();
              })
            }, 3000);
          });
        });
      }, 6000);
    });
  });
});
```

(Sorry for the callback piramid).

Running this on my system:

```
[zlatko@desktop-mint ~/tmp]$ node test.js
Setting key...
Setting expire on the key...
Waiting 6 sec before checking expire time...
expiryTime: 4
Expiring key again...
Waiting 3 more sec before checking expire time...
New expiryTime: 7
[zlatko@desktop-mint ~/tmp]$
```

As you can see, we set expire time to 10 seconds. After 6 seconds, obviously the time left is 4 seconds.

If we at that moment, with 4 seconds to go, set the expire to 10 again, we simply start over from 10.
3 seconds after that, we're still good for 7 more seconds.

Comment: Thanks, from the Redis docs "The timeout will only be cleared by commands that delete or overwrite the contents of the key, including DEL, SET, GETSET and all the *STORE commands..." So it looks like I need to be careful to call EXPIRE after SET is called, not the other way around. However if SET always clears the timeout, then the docs don't make that clear...I guess I need to know if SET always clears the timeout.

Comment: Yeah, but you can also use `setex` which sets and expires the key atomically.

Comment: Also, SET does not clear the timeout. Just adds the new value to a key that potentially exists with optional timeout from before.